# How to fix send to menu in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, send-to

I've recently bought an Windows 8-powered notebook and since first start I have problems with context send-to menu.

Look at the screenshot.

[image: Broken send-to]

The folder displays contents of my shell:sendto folder. But despite all usual items are present, the send to menu consists only of "send e-mail".

How can I fix it?

---

**Edit:** In response to comments:

Contents of Desktop.ini of this folder:

```
[LocalizedFileNames]
Fax Recipient.lnk=@%SystemRoot%\system32\FXSRESM.dll,-120
Mail Recipient.MAPIMail=@sendmail.dll,-4
Desktop (create shortcut).DeskLink=@sendmail.dll,-21
Compressed (zipped) Folder.ZFSendToTarget=@zipfldr.dll,-10148
Documents.mydocs=@shell32.dll,-34575
Transfer plików Bluetooth.LNK=@C:\Windows\System32\fsquirt.exe,-2343
```

Comment: Try this: http://www.askvg.com/how-to-restore-missing-send-to-menuitem-in-file-and-folder-context-menus/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it won't help. I already have such entry in System Registry...

Comment: Right click and check properties. If those entries are set as hidden they do not appear in the context menu.

Comment: They are not. Right click on the bluetooth icon hangs permanently this window of Explorer, though.

Comment: Can you post the content of your Desktop.ini file in that particular directory please?

Comment: Sure, I've edited my post.

Comment: Try `sfc /scannow` in an elevated command-prompt and report back after its done (do a restart after its done). I cannot think of anything else.

Comment: Will the following appear in the SendTo menu: Once you're in the SendTo folder create a new i.e. New Document.txt but then rename that to Desktop (create shortcut).DeskLink ?

Comment: After an attempt to use Bluetooth, Windows crashed with a bluescreen. Oddly enough, after a restart, all options suddenly appeared in the Send To menu. Now, when I add another option, as you suggested, it appears in the menu immediately. I'm also able to call properties on a bluetooth send-to link. That's weird.

Answer (score 1):

Chance are that your **sendto folder** is **corrupted**.  (You can use **shell:sendto** in Run to locate)

If that is the case, you can fix it using [Advanced System Care.](http://www.iobit.com/downloadcenter.php?product=advanced-systemcare-free)

Check the page http://www.iobit.com/help/asc/doc/toolbox.html.  Search for **IE Helper**.  IE Helper will help you restore your default context menu.

Caution : Since the OS language is **not** English, there is a risk that **ASC** will tamper with your registries regarding contect menu incorrectly.